# Does the kubernetes configMaps can set pod information as environment

Tags: kubernetes

if a pod yaml like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_POD_NAME HOST_PATH;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: my-config
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metsdata.nodeName
```

I want to use ConfigMaps to define service anvironment
But some environemnt will use MY_POD_NAME var

I set my configMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
  HOST_PATH: "$(MY_POD_NAME)-test"
```

But I found in container, the HOST_PATH is wrong,
it display **$(MY_POD_NAME)-test** not **test-container-sxdwwwa-test**

thanks.

Comment: May be try removing the double quotes from $(MY_POD_NAME)-test.

Comment: @poling CHEN Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community?

Comment: sorry, it is not worked